# calculating directory size in cocoa

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I want to calculate the directory (folder)size and i have to list all files and folders (subfolders) in a volume(drive) with its corresponding size.I am using the below code to calculate size.The problem with this code is the performance issue . I am using `NSBrowser` to display .

```
NSArray *filesArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:nil];
NSEnumerator *filesEnumerator = [filesArray objectEnumerator];
NSString *fileName;
unsigned long long int fileSize = 0;

while (fileName = [filesEnumerator nextObject]) 
{
    NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:folderPath error:nil];
    fileSize += [fileDictionary fileSize];
}

return fileSize;
```

Questions:

1. Is there any built in function available?
2. If not what is the best way to calculate the size?
3. Is it good to use cache to store already calculated file size?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stat`.

```
-(unsigned long long)getFolderSize : (NSString *)folderPath;

{
    char *dir = (char *)[folderPath fileSystemRepresentation];
DIR *cd;

struct dirent *dirinfo;
int lastchar;
struct stat linfo;
static unsigned long long totalSize = 0;

cd = opendir(dir);

if (!cd) {
    return 0;
}

while ((dirinfo = readdir(cd)) != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(dirinfo->d_name, ".") && strcmp(dirinfo->d_name, "..")) {
        char *d_name;


        d_name = (char*)malloc(strlen(dir)+strlen(dirinfo->d_name)+2);

        if (!d_name) {
            //out of memory
            closedir(cd);
            exit(1);
        }

        strcpy(d_name, dir);
        lastchar = strlen(dir) - 1;
        if (lastchar >= 0 && dir[lastchar] != '/')
            strcat(d_name, "/");
        strcat(d_name, dirinfo->d_name);

        if (lstat(d_name, &linfo) == -1) {
            free(d_name);
            continue;
        }
        if (S_ISDIR(linfo.st_mode)) {
            if (!S_ISLNK(linfo.st_mode))
                [self getFolderSize:[NSString stringWithCString:d_name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            free(d_name);
        } else {
            if (S_ISREG(linfo.st_mode)) {
                totalSize+=linfo.st_size;
            } else {
                free(d_name);
            }
        }
    }
}

closedir(cd);

return totalSize;

}
```

Take a look at [Mac OS X not reporting directory sizes correctly?](https://superuser.com/questions/382120/mac-os-x-not-reporting-directory-sizes-correctly)

Comment: Is that really much different to the OP's approach?

Comment: @Yatheesha If you are not targeting 10.8 osx. You can use Carbon API. Take a look at [Obtain directory size.](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/136498-obtain-directory-size.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
  1. Is there any built in function available?
```

`fileSize` is a built-in function that gives you size.

```
  2. If not what is the best way to calculate the size?
```

This method is good enough to calculate size of a folder/directory.

```
  3. Is it good to use cache to store already calculated file size?
```

Yes you can store it in cache.

Comment: fileSize gives only the internal size of the folder not full size.

Comment: assume the folder size 2Gb .If i use fileSize i will get size less than MB  its not full size.